# PHP - Compare time with milliseconds

Tags: php, time, compare

How do I compare two times with milliseconds in PHP? Ie., I have times like this:

- 00:38.673
- 00:38.652

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Parses the inputed string
sscanf('00:38.673', "%d:%d.%d", $minutes, $seconds, $miliseconds);

// Convert it to miliseconds
$mseconds = $seconds * 1000 + $minutes * 60 * 1000 + $miliseconds;
```